# GlobalAlloc instead of other allocation method

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, heap-memory

While going through code on MSDN for [finding the owner of the given file object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/finding-the-owner-of-a-file-object-in-c--), the program uses `GlobalAlloc()` to allocate the memory to `AcctName`. Since I'm new to using the Win32 API, my curiosity made me enquired why we are using `GlobalAlloc()` instead of other allocation methods. If other better allocation methods exist, how to use them in the given code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "accctrl.h"
#include "aclapi.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")

int main(void)
{
DWORD dwRtnCode = 0;
PSID pSidOwner = NULL;
BOOL bRtnBool = TRUE;
LPTSTR AcctName = NULL;
LPTSTR DomainName = NULL;
DWORD dwAcctName = 1, dwDomainName = 1;
SID_NAME_USE eUse = SidTypeUnknown;
HANDLE hFile;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;


// Get the handle of the file object.
hFile = CreateFile(
                  TEXT("myfile.txt"),
                  GENERIC_READ,
                  FILE_SHARE_READ,
                  NULL,
                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                  NULL);

// Check GetLastError for CreateFile error code.
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          _tprintf(TEXT("CreateFile error = %d\n"), dwErrorCode);
          return -1;
}



// Get the owner SID of the file.
dwRtnCode = GetSecurityInfo(
                  hFile,
                  SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                  OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                  &pSidOwner,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  NULL,
                  &pSD);

// Check GetLastError for GetSecurityInfo error condition.
if (dwRtnCode != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          _tprintf(TEXT("GetSecurityInfo error = %d\n"), dwErrorCode);
          return -1;
}

// First call to LookupAccountSid to get the buffer sizes.
bRtnBool = LookupAccountSid(
                  NULL,           // local computer
                  pSidOwner,
                  AcctName,
                  (LPDWORD)&dwAcctName,
                  DomainName,
                  (LPDWORD)&dwDomainName,
                  &eUse);

// Reallocate memory for the buffers.
AcctName = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(
          GMEM_FIXED,
          dwAcctName);

// Check GetLastError for GlobalAlloc error condition.
if (AcctName == NULL) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          _tprintf(TEXT("GlobalAlloc error = %d\n"), dwErrorCode);
          return -1;
}

    DomainName = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(
           GMEM_FIXED,
           dwDomainName);

    // Check GetLastError for GlobalAlloc error condition.
    if (DomainName == NULL) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          _tprintf(TEXT("GlobalAlloc error = %d\n"), dwErrorCode);
          return -1;

    }

    // Second call to LookupAccountSid to get the account name.
    bRtnBool = LookupAccountSid(
          NULL,                   // name of local or remote computer
          pSidOwner,              // security identifier
          AcctName,               // account name buffer
          (LPDWORD)&dwAcctName,   // size of account name buffer 
          DomainName,             // domain name
          (LPDWORD)&dwDomainName, // size of domain name buffer
          &eUse);                 // SID type

    // Check GetLastError for LookupAccountSid error condition.
    if (bRtnBool == FALSE) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;

          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();

          if (dwErrorCode == ERROR_NONE_MAPPED)
              _tprintf(TEXT
                  ("Account owner not found for specified SID.\n"));
          else 
              _tprintf(TEXT("Error in LookupAccountSid.\n"));
          return -1;

    } else if (bRtnBool == TRUE) 

        // Print the account name.
        _tprintf(TEXT("Account owner = %s\n"), AcctName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is flawed and has memory leaks since there are no calls to `GlobalFree`.

Comment: There's no reason to use `GlobalAlloc` specifically here; any method of obtaining a buffer of sufficient size will do. And yes, the program leaks those buffers.

Comment: An appropriately sized `std::vector<TCHAR>` can be used for the call to `LookupAccountSid` instead of those allocated buffers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you please provide the code snippet on how to use another method?

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik Can you explain how I can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone.
I have just modified my code by using `malloc`.

```
    AccountBuff = (LPSTR)malloc(AccountBufflength * sizeof(LPSTR));
    DomainBuff = (LPSTR)malloc(DomainBufflength * sizeof(LPSTR));
```

Comment: Note that Visual C++ implementation of ``malloc`` and ``new`` just end up calling ``HeapAlloc`` using the ``GetProcessHeap`` default. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc). The only time you need to use the legacy ``GlobalAlloc`` for modern applications is dealing with the [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard). If you want to implement your own memory manager, you'll usually end up calling ``VirtualAlloc``.

Answer (score 1):

See [this Microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/comparing-memory-allocation-methods) for an overview of the different memory allocation functions that currently exist in Microsoft Windows.

Basically, `GlobalAlloc` is a remnant of [16-bit Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.1x). In 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, there is no longer a distinction between `GlobalAlloc` and `LocalAlloc`, as modern operating systems use a [flat memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model). If you are interested in what significance these functions had in 16-bit Windows, you can read [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041101-00/?p=37433) by Microsoft blogger Raymond Chen.

As stated in the [offical documentation of the function `GlobalAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalalloc), this function should generally not be used in modern 32-bit or 64-bit applications, except in situations where the documentation specifically tells you to do so.

Since the [official documentation on the function `LookupAccountSid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsida) does not specify that any of the passed buffers must have been allocated with `GlobalAlloc`, there is no reason to use this function. It would be more appropriate to for example use the function [`HeapAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc), as this function has lower overhead than `GlobalAlloc`. Alternatively, you can use normal C++ memory allocations (for example `new` or `std::vector`), which, depending on the implementation, probably calls the function `HeapAlloc` indirectly.

Comment: Because Microsoft likes to break blog links, so next year's readers will have to search for it: The blog post is titled "What was the difference between LocalAlloc and GlobalAlloc?"

Comment: Raymond Chen's blog is now hosted in "devblogs". The article you want is [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041101-00/?p=37433)

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: As far as I can tell, the link you just posted is identical to the link I posted in my answer. The person named "user253751" additionally posted the name of the article in case Microsoft breaks this link. Therefore, there is no point in you posting the same link as a comment.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. The 'personal developer blogs' on MSDN Blogs were shutdown over the past few years, which is probably why user253751 was frustrated. Raymond Chen and a number of others ended up at the Visual Studio devblogs. Others like [myself](https://walbourn.github.io/) and [ShawnHar](http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html) ended up migrating to other platforms.